# Transaction fees on smart contract token as loyalty points

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20, tokens

As at ethereum mentioned, token ERC20 can be used as Loyalty points. So consider a Forex website which wants to send 1 of its token to each clients who have traded 1 lot or so. In other words its smart contract event has coded to sending token per each trade or even for each sign up in its website.
my question is if the transaction fees apply to all sending token as loyalty points to the website's clients, it will be horrible and gainless.
I am starting to learn solidity , so maybe I'm in a wrong way. please help me know there is the transaction fees? and if it is what is the minimum amount?

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to understand what you want, could you be more precise and format your question? One big paragraph is complicated to analyze :S

Comment: @Andromelus thanks for comment. assume I am smart token owner. I have a website that I give 1 token to each visitor who sign up in my website. this is an event of my solidity. I'm asking do I have to spend transaction fee for each registered visitor when he gives his token?

Comment: Then @smarx answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every change to the blockchain happens as part of a transaction, and every transaction has a transaction fee associated with it.

Giving someone a token, then, requires paying a transaction fee. Fees vary depending on demand and how quickly you need the transaction to be processed. In recent history, fees have ranged from a few cents to a couple dollars.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer, so practically it's impossible to give smart tokens to my register clients, as loyalty point, because it doesn't worth. So should I focus on EOS insted?

Comment: I don't have anything to add to my answer. Only you know the value of tracking these loyalty points on the blockchain, so only you can determine if it's worth it to you or not.